# Conjugate Gradient with a noisy function

Tags: neural-network, mathematical-optimization

OK, so I'm doing RMS prop or SGD to get a neural network to learn it's parameters. But, after a while, both training and validation errors appear to have stagnated (outside of random fluctuations: I'm using dropout)..

So, I decided, to try to use conjugate gradient to refine the values. I still obviously don't want it to overfit, so I was keeping the dropout... But, of course, this makes the optimization function be noisy. So, I guess my question is: Does Conjugate Gradient (or L-BFGS or etc.) require noiseless functions? Or can they work in the presence of noise?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Gradient-based optimization algorithms are highly sensitive to noise. This is because the derivative calculation gets affected due to the discontinuities caused by the noise across the function domain.

To optimize noisy objective functions it is better to use heuristic algorithms: Genetic Algorithms, Simulated Annealing, Ant Colony, Particle Swarm... They Are not based on gradients and therefore they do not present the same weakness.

You can read more about these algorithms in the book:

Duc Pham, D. Karaboga, *Intelligent Optimisation Techniques*. London, United Kingdom: Springer-Verlag London, 2000.

If you are interested in Simulated Annealing, you can also read:

Peter Rossmanith, “Simulated Annealing” in *Algorithms Unplugged*, Vöcking, B., Alt, H., Dietzfelbinger, M., Reischuk, R., Scheideler, C., Vollmer, H., Wagner, D., Ed. Berlin, Germany: Springer-Verlag Berlin Heidelberg, 2011, ch. 41, pp. 393-400.